# Как отпарсить xml настроек со списком Preference элементов?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-shared-preferences, android-preferences

Добрый день!
Подскажите как можно отпарсить xml настроек со списком Preference элементов, так чтобы мне на выходе получить android:title и текущее значение каждой опции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();

for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
    Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());            
}
```